# Problem with Building a CSS Grid Template

Tags: css, css-grid

i try to build following css grid template but struggling with the last 3 items.

has anyone an idea to resolve this?

i think the problem is maybe the height of the second row (items 4,5,6)

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 30px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);

    .col {
        
        &:nth-child(10n+1),
        &:nth-child(10n+2),
        &:nth-child(10n+10) {
            grid-column: auto / span 3;
            height: 580px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        &:nth-child(10n+3),
        &:nth-child(10n+7) {
            grid-column: auto / span 6;
            height: 580px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        
        &:nth-child(10n+4),
        &:nth-child(10n+5),
        &:nth-child(10n+6) {
            grid-column: auto / span 4;
            height: 430px;
            background-color: green;
        }

        &:nth-child(10n+8),
        &:nth-child(10n+9) {
            grid-column: auto / span 3;
            height: 275px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Template:

[image: Template]

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Add the HTML. It helps to provide enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are almost good, you simply need to adjust the start of the last blue div so it's below the first one. You can also change the way you are setting the height like below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /* this will fix the position of the last red */
}

.grid .col:nth-child(10n+1),
.grid .col:nth-child(10n+2),
.grid .col:nth-child(10n+10) {
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-row: span 2; /* take two rows */
  background-color: red;
  height:200px; /* define the height for only the red and the blue, yellow will follow */
}

.grid .col:nth-child(10n+3),
.grid .col:nth-child(10n+7) {
  grid-column:span 6;
  grid-row: span 2; /* also take two rows */
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grid .col:nth-child(10n+4),
.grid .col:nth-child(10n+5),
.grid .col:nth-child(10n+6) {
  grid-column:span 4;
  background-color: green;
  height:150px; /* the green are alone so they need a height */
}

.grid .col:nth-child(10n+8),
.grid .col:nth-child(10n+9) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  background-color: blue;
}
/* this will fix your issue */
.grid .col:nth-child(10n+9) {
  grid-column-start:7
}
/* */
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```